# How to handle application level redirects in Nginx with Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, alpine-linux, crystal-lang

I am writing an Nginx configurations for Crystal-Lang based application to send all the traffic `http://example.com/videos/` to `http://0.0.0.0:3000` via reverse proxy.

I have written the following config which is not working and I'm heading over the internet but no luck.

When I go to `http://example.com/videos/`, application internally performing a redirect from `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/feed/popular` which is the problem, it redirects to `http://example.com/feed/popular` which is wrong, I need `/videos/` part to always concatenated with URL like `http://example.com/videos/xxxx` always but after redirect the `/videos/` part is being chopped out.
So the application should consider `http://example.com/videos/` as host.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name elearn.com.pk default_server localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    location /videos/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        rewrite /videos/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host/videos/;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue please? Thanks.

Comment: Where is feed/popular coming from?

Comment: from application

Comment: same problem but still not find any solution

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `proxy_redirect` to force change the header of `Location` the upstream returned redirect.**

If I want nginx to dispatch the path `foo` to an upstream app with listen port is 7001, the simplest configure:

```txt
location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:7001/;
}
```

However, for my situation, this reverse proxied upstream app will return a redirect of `301 Moved Permanently` with header `Location:/bar/` when user successfully login. (You can know how the redirect works by tracing network activity via DevTools of a browser.)

I want `xxx.com/foo/bar` => `localhost:7001/bar`, but because the incorrect `Location` of its redirect, by combing the `host` header it will return `xxx.com/bar` to clients. The problem is, it will require nginx to look location `location /bar/ {...}`, which is not configured at all.

---

Naturally, one brutal way in my head is to use another redirect to correct the url:

```txt
location / {
    ...
    rewrite /bar/.* /foo/bar/$1;
}
# OR
location /bar/ {
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host/foo/bar/;
}
```

---

After thinking, I realize a more favorable solution is to just change the Location of the returned redirect package directly. Fortunately, the `proxy_redirect` of nginx provides this function to allow us change the Location of proxied redirect.

> Syntax: proxy_redirect redirect replacement;

from: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect.

OK, here is the solution:

```txt
location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:7001/;
    proxy_redirect /bar/ /foo/bar/;
    # you may need to debug what content of "Location" in your wrong redirect package by DevTools, and replace it here.
}
```

A simply way to replace the wrong Location from `/bar/` to `/foo/bar/` the `Location` field fixed my problem.

PS: a trick of debuggin nginx and network activity is to use new “Incognito window” every time. Or the browser cache will give you misleading reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the redirect comes from the proxied application, you need to rewrite the `Location` header to match the prefix path on the proxy server.

[`proxy_redirect off`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) is causing this error. You need to set it to `default` or configure a custom rewrite (`default` should work fine for your purpose, though).

Comment: Hello I'm new to nginx, would you please include the exact solution to your answer please? that would be more beneficial for the people have this issue.

Comment: All the necessary information is available in the referenced documentation. Easiest solution is to just remove this line.
If you can't parse the nginx documentation, I'd suggest to reconsider if you should really be running this software.

Answer (score 0):

You should define [`upstream`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#example) in `http` directive.

```
http {
# ...

  upstream myapp {
    server 0.0.0.0:3000;
  }

# ...

}
```

Then use it in the `server` scope in `location` like this:

```
location ^~ /video/ {
  proxy_pass http://myapp;
}
```

Comment: not work for me